# How to toggle second row of Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap, and I'm building a navbar with a second row. The second row is only called when the search box it contains is required. To call it, I have an always-visible button-styled-link that works perfectly in mobile device widths, but will not hide it in desktop widths. What am I not getting? Below is the HTML, and [here's a Bootply sample](http://www.bootply.com/RGNt9xF3CQ). Thanks in advance... `

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav1">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-inverse navbar-btn" href="#" title="Search" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav2">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search white"></span>
        </a>    
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Title">Brand</a>         
    </div>
</div>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav2">
  <form class="navbar-form" role="search" id="srch-frm">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control typeahead" placeholder="Search" name="pn" id="srch-term" type="text">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form> 
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very nice. Just remove "navbar-collapse" on the collapse surrounding the search.

http://www.bootply.com/5fUw0Xo2vX

```
<div class="collapse" id="nav2">
  <form class="navbar-form" role="search" id="srch-frm">
  ....
```

Comment: I need to stop looking at Bootstrap questions so late at night, you always beat me to the answer.... +1 for a nice simple solution!

Comment: What does navbar-collapse do?

Comment: @KayceBasques - it's just for the .navbar-nav  -- if you want to know what things do go to the Repository and/or download bootstrap and look at the unminified CSS.

Comment: @DavidG - I don't know about that. You and I had almost the same rep a week or so ago and now you're thousands ahead of me. Do you do jQuery work?

Comment: @Christina Didn't think I'd gained that much in the last 2 weeks but it seems to work out at around 1800 or so. Some days seem to be much easier than others! I do indeed so some jQuery, why do you ask? Actually, this is way offtopic, we can continue in chat instead :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64241/bootstrap-for-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks Christina, and everyone else too.

Comment: you're welcome, but it was just me. David and I were having another conversation. If you open up the unminified css you will see that navbar-collapse is used to keep the collapse from responding at the min-width, so it will always show, if you use that class, it will never go away.